# Find with multiple rename

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename

I need to rename several million files with multiple patterns.
Some filenames have a few characters that i want to replace.
In order not to scan all files multiple times I want to do all the replacements at once.

I tried these scripts:

```
find . -type f -name '*\.jpg' -exec rename 's/%c3%a0/\xc3\xa0/g' {} \; -exec rename 's/%c3%a9/\xc3\xa9/g' {} \; -exec rename 's/%c3%aa/\xc3\xaa/g' {} \;

find . -type f -name '*\.jpg' -exec rename 's/%c3%a0/\xc3\xa0/g' | -exec rename 's/%c3%a9/\xc3\xa9/g' | -exec rename 's/%c3%aa/\xc3\xaa/g'
```

These scripts replace only one character.

Help pls.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you want to rename your files? What's your input? Expected output? It would make our lives easier if you could describe a little more, instead of expecting from us to decipher your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your first `rename` renames the file, so when you `exec` your second `rename` on the same file, it has already gone because it has been renamed by the first one!

I think you will get on much better doing all the substitutions in one go, it will also save executing `rename` multiple times per file:

```
find ... -exec rename 's/a/b/g; s/c/d/g; s/e/f/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Of course something like `rename '/%(\x\x)/ chr(oct("0x$1"))/ge'` would require just a single invocation, but I have no idea if there is a `rename` which exposes this amount of its internals. Maybe rewrite as a Perl one-liner then.

Comment: @triplee I believe you can write as big and complicated a script as you like in there.

Comment: There are many `rename` implementations but if the one you use supports this, good for you! (-: